# What does this mean "This method is deprecated as the user should use the Java 5 conventions."?

Tags: java, conventions, opencsv

I am using the "ColumnPositionMappingStrategy" class of the `opencvs` library.
This class has the `deprecated` method `setType(Class<T> type)` and as comment has "*This method is deprecated as the user should use the Java 5 conventions*"

As far as I understand is that I have to use Generics instead of setType like:

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<MyClass> mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
```

to solve the problem. But I get `NullPointerException` when I remove the line:

```
mappingStrategy.setType(MyClass.class);
```

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing CSV!
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:95)
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:75)
at csv_import.ReadCsvFile.readRecordData(ReadCsvFile.java:40)
at app.Application.main(Application.java:30)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.createBean(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:170)
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.processLine(CsvToBean.java:117)
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.processLine(CsvToBean.java:101)
at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:91)
... 3 more
```

What do I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you get the the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Another approach to figure "what to do" ... turn to the source code of that class; and see what "setType()" is actually doing. Then check the interface of the class for an alternative to do "the same".

Comment: @PaulRuane please see the error in the question.

Comment: @EddyG the `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy` has the method createBean which uses the `Class<T> type` to instantiate the class, the `type` is set by the `setType` method that is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation relies on the type by calling:

```
public T createBean() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  return type.newInstance();
}
```

Some comments like this one - `TODO refactor this class to use T instead of getType.` - imply that the `@Deprecation` annotations have been used too early - as there is no alternative usage available.